# Getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, function, html-table, href

Function is not defined but it is and I can't see why.

Using a href  and onclick both get the same error.  I've used this in other pages and it works but I can't get it to work in another page

Tried:

`<td><a href="javascript:divShowHide('preMP');" id="#mID#">#mNo#</a></td>`

Tried:

`<td onclick="divShowHide('preMP');">#mNo#</td>`

Function:

```
<script>
function divShowHide(showDiv) {

  if (document.getElementById(showDiv).style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById(showDiv).style.display = 'block';
  } 
  else {
    document.getElementById(showDiv).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

Want to show this:

```
<div id="preMP" style="display:none">                                                                                                      
 <cfif preExists NEQ "">                                                                                                       
     <cfloop query="qPreviousMPs">                                                                                                         
     <cfset mpCNT=mpCNT + 1>                                                                                                            
         <tr>                                                                                                                 
             <td style="display:none;">#qPreviousMPs.ID#</td>                                                                                                           
             <td colspan="1">Comments(<cfoutput>#mpCNT#</cfoutput>)</td>                                                                                                           
             <td colspan="1"><cfoutput>#qPreviousMPs.previousMP#</cfoutput></td>                                                                                                                      
         </tr>                                                                                                       
     </cfloop>                                                                                                     
 </cfif>
</div>
```

Error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: divShowHide is not defined
    at :1:1

Comment: Hi malibu65k. It'd be helpful for others here if you could set up a quick demo of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the script is on same page as the caller and no Js error exist before the function? Because the code looks clean to me.

Answer (score 1):

You were not to clear on what your problem is but I think it has something to do with your html. Make sure you call the script containing your show/hide function using the SCRIPT tags.